# How do you set the 'linebreakmode' for an android textview (FormattedText)

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android, textview

I'm from iOS and tackling android dev using Mono (Xamarin). Is there a way to set the textview linebreak mode for the textview like we do for iOS.

When I set the Text attribute for the TextView it auto word wraps correctly, however if I set the Text with a SpannableString it doesn't word wrap, instead it character wraps with no ellipsize.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use a SpannableString? The simplest answer is to just use a normal String, which will behave how you want it to.